# Difference between Salesforce status site & status-ins site

Tags: alert, trust

I have come across two status sites for Salesforce. One is https://salesforce-ins.statuspage.io/# and another being https://status.salesforce.com/. I am able to find the instance of my org on `status.salesforce.com` but not on `salesforce-ins.statuspage.io`. The reason I am looking for is Opsgenie is referencing `salesforce-ins.statuspage.io` for status updates and my org isn't on that site.

Comment: Statuspage is a separate company and a separate service (currently owned by Atlassian at time of writing). I can tell you from personal experience that Statuspage is pretty painful to work with (inconsistent API design, poor and occasionally incorrect documentation, abysmal response examples). It wouldn't surprise me if Salesforce went "Well, this service makes our half-baked initial release of Lightning look good. We can probably do it better in-house" but that's entirely speculation.

Comment: @DerekF We were like seconds apart, lol.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statuspage.io appears to be an Atlassian product, running on AWS hosting services. Honestly, there's no immediate tell if this is a legitimate page or something some other company or individual set up. The official page is https://status.salesforce.com/, and is the one you should use to check for your instance's status.

Comment: thank you. Prompt & super helpful as always.